# Oracle Select Query Specific Case

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I got below table,

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Yes | 1 |
| Banana | No | 2 |
| Orange | Yes | 3 |
| Apple | Yes | 4 |
| Apple | Yes | 5 |
| Apple | Yes | 6 |
| Banana | No | 7 |

I want to make a query that selects the fruits that have only "No" as a value for col2.
In this case it's 'Banana'.

Thanks

Comment: Orange doesn't have a value of No in col2.  It only has a value of Yes.  Banana is the only col1 value that is ever associated with a No in col2.  Do you really want the result to be Banana?

Comment: *Banana. Sorry for that

Comment: Please, provide sample data [in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/285557#285557). You can use [ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for this.

Comment: Are the only possible values in `col2` **Yes** and **No**? And, can `col2` be `null` - and in that case, how should that be handled re: your requirement?

Comment: @mathguy, yes and no are the only values. And null is not a case.

Comment: @astentx Done. Thx for the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause.  Using the fact that `'Yes' > 'No'`:

```
select fruit
from t
group by fruit
having max(col2) = 'No';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon ! This is a great help.